# can a applet open a socket connection to its server

Tags: java, applet

can a applet open socket connection to the server?

Comment: i want to build a chat system using this applet

Answer (score 3):

> Untrusted applets can only communicate back to the server from which they came (the host that delivered the .class files). If you need to communicate with another server, you'll either have to sign your applet (and the user will have to trust you), or setup a proxy server on your web server to facility the communication between hosts.

So yes you can open a socket to your own server.

---

**Resources :**

- [How can my applet open a socket connection to a machine other than the web server?](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=26657)